# Change Azure AD password policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

Is there a way to edit the password policy by increasing the minimum password length from 8 - 12 in Azure AD or Office 365 admin center?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not supported at this moment.

You can vote [this idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/36849511-azure-ad-password-policy) on User Voice.

Besides, based on [Requiring long passwords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/misc/password-policy-recommendations?view=o365-worldwide#requiring-long-passwords):

> Password length requirements (greater than about 10 characters) can
>   result in user behavior that is predictable and undesirable. For
>   example, users who are required to have a 16-character password may
>   choose repeating patterns like fourfourfourfour or passwordpassword
>   that meet the character length requirement but aren't hard to guess.
>   Additionally, length requirements increase the chances that users will
>   adopt other insecure practices, such as writing their passwords down,
>   re-using them, or storing them unencrypted in their documents. To
>   encourage users to think about a unique password, we recommend keeping
>   a reasonable 8-character minimum length requirement.